# Setting up the path so AWS cli works properly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I installed AWSCLI by using:

```
pip install --upgrade --user awscli
```

Now if I type aws configure in the cmd I get: 'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

I'm pretty sure the path needs to be set correctly.  I know how to go into the environment variables to set the path, but I don't know WHAT to set the path to because I don't see where `awscli` is installed. By the way, I already have boto3 installed and I'm able to import that just fine.

I should also mention I'm setting this up in windows.

Comment: Have you modified your path as described here? - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html

Answer (score 9):

Hi I just had the same problem, and I managed to solve this!

I'm using python 3.7.0 and pip version 18.

I installed awscli using

```
pip install --upgrade --user awscli
```

but it is not added in PATH, and I have no idea how to find it.But when I decided to delete it, running

```
pip uninstall awscli
```

it told me that

```
Uninstalling awscli-1.15.65:
Would remove:
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\aws
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\aws.cmd
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\aws_bash_completer
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\aws_completer
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\aws_zsh_completer.sh
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\awscli-1.15.65.dist-info\*
    c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\awscli\*
```

So I know the file was installed in

`c:\users\riz\appdata\roaming\python\python37\scripts\aws`

you just need to add this to PATH! Good Luck!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html says that you should set the path to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts if you use pip, but the path for me was actually %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts. You can search for aws.cmd to find where it was actually installed. Just add that directory to  your path environmental variable. I'm using Python 2.7 so that might explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:
1. upgrade existing aws-cli
2. do a clean install

here are the steps to do a clean install:

remove any existing aws-cli rpms's: pip remove aws-cli

curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"

pip -y install unzip

unzip awscli-bundle.zip

./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws

aws --version

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to install awscli on windows 10 x64. I was installing awscli using command below (which recommended from the following guide ([Installing the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)):

```
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

But after I run that command, I still can't run aws --version command. It said that aws is not recognized. So after some triage, the only works and easy way to install awscli is download the awscli is using the msi installer provided by Amazon itself:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html

Just run, install, no extra configuration needed, restart your command line, and it works like charm.