# AWS cli windows - still getting "'aws' is not recognized..." after adding path to environment variables?

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

Following instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099986/setting-up-the-path-so-aws-cli-works-properly) (and elsewhere) I added '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\aws' to Path (tried with and without \aws at the end)

[image]

I clicked OK everywhere and restartet the CLI, but I am still getting "'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." when typing aws at the command prompt (I restarted it after the path update). Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening the command prompt? Because those will take effect only in new command prompt afaik.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that yes, I did restart the command prompt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if this is in a windows machine By default, the CLI installs to C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI (64-bit version) or C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon\AWSCLI (32-bit version). So I guess the PATH that you've added is incorrect.

try checking this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html#awscli-install-windows-path

run the command - where aws

once you know where it was installed then copy that and it to your path. i hope this helps.

Comment: I was doing it through pip install which places it in that folder. I was entering the path in the wrong field I believe. IN the end I did pip uninstall and rant the windows installer instead to have the path set automatically

Comment: After adding the path (including if it was automatically added by the installer) you need to restart your pc for the IDEs to be able to access aws.

Answer (score 2):

Resuming. The first answer is complemented bye the second. Because is important add to "Path" environment for aws CLI the path where is installed the CLI (executing the comand "where aws" in cmd . After this one reboot to the machine must recognize the commands.