# error when using script OIDv4 to download images. error: aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm using script OIDv4 to automatically download annotated images for YOLOv3 from Open Image Dataset found here: https://github.com/pythonlessons/OIDv4_ToolKit

This is part of a larger exercise where i want to download annotated images to train my YOLOv3 model. https://pylessons.com/YOLOv3-TF2-custrom-train

The code seems to work and creates all the folders but they are empty without the images. I get the error: "'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file", which is repeated many times over, each time for every image i believe.

Following other stacked overflow answers like the one listed below, i added environment variable ("C:\Users\lingy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\awscli")
[AWS cli windows - still getting "'aws' is not recognized..." after adding path to environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712835/aws-cli-windows-still-getting-aws-is-not-recognized-after-adding-path-t/55713297#55713297)

I run this in the terminal: " py main.py downloader --classes 'Clothing' 'Hat' 'Suit' 'Swimwear' 'Trousers' --type_csv test --limit 200"

main.py code is as below:

'''

```
OID v4 Downloader
Download specific classes of the huge online dataset Open Image Dataset.
Licensed under the MIT License (see LICENSE for details)
------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
refer to README.md file
"""
from sys import exit
from textwrap import dedent
from modules.parser import *
from modules.utils import *
from modules.downloader import *
from modules.show import *
from modules.csv_downloader import *
from modules.bounding_boxes import *
from modules.image_level import *


ROOT_DIR = ''
DEFAULT_OID_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'OID')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = parser_arguments()

    if args.command == 'downloader_ill':
        image_level(args, DEFAULT_OID_DIR)
    else:
        bounding_boxes_images(args, DEFAULT_OID_DIR)
```

'''
Using windows 10, python 3.10.4 64bit in VS studio code.

Comment: Did you install requirements?

Comment: yes , but i solved it now.  i uninstalled awscli and reinstalled it again using the .exe file i found from the website  instead of using pip install.